# Windows XP: finding services on a machine that the current user can modify

Tags: windows, privilege-escalation

I've looked up the accesschk.exe tool which is one way to find services with weak permissions that allow exploitation of the access control model. What is a manual way to do this if I can't get accesschk.exe onto the remote machine?

Say there are also about 50 services to check, and no ability to repeat the last command, meaning most of the command must be manually retyped. Currently the only solution I can think of is writing a script that would attempt to manually change the binPath of all services, and then I'd go through the echoed results to see which did not return an access denied error.

However I'm not so great at scripting, so looking for solutions which avoid that; however if someone does have a script handy that would serve as a solution I would be happy to take it off his/her hands.